# Is it possible to configure an HTTP header in WebSphere response?

Tags: http, websphere-7

I need to add an HTTP header for all the responses of all applications installed on a WebSphere 7.0 (no Http server installed, only WAS), I have to add this header for every resources, not only for jsp or servlet but also for images and javascripts.

Is it possible to configure WebSphere 7.0 to add a specific HTTP header for all the responses?

If isn't possible to configure WebSphere? Is It possible configure an HTTP Server for the same work?